# Get filtered values from nested object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary, object

I have a list of objects with every object of the form:

```
{
  "myFilters": [
    {
      "isMatch": false,
      "filters": [
        {
          "id": "aaaaaa",
          "version": "v1"
        },
        {
          "id": "kk",
          "version": "v1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "randomAttr1": null,
  "randomAttr2": []
}
```

Assume that the above is an object from a list of objects stored in `result`.

Now I want to get a list of all the **versions** and add it back to this object as value of a new element `relevant_versions` but with a condition that the Id and version must be in the URL parameters. Here is my attempt at it:

```
  for (let f of result) {
    f.relevant_versions = f.myFilters.filter(x=>x.filters    
    .filter(item=>(item.id == this.$route.params.filterId && item.version == this.$route.params.version))
    .map(fid => fid.version))
  }
```

But I instead have the entire `myFilters` element instead of the versions only. I think I'm close and making a simple mistake here.

How can I appropriately populate relevant_versions here?

Edit: So the output would look like

```
{
  "myFilters": [
    {
      "isMatch": false,
      "filters": [
        {
          "id": "aaaaaa",
          "version": "v1"
        },
        {
          "id": "kk",
          "version": "v1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "randomAttr1": null,
  "randomAttr2": [],
  "relevant_versions":["v1", "v1"]
}
```

A sample route is `localhost:8080/filters/kk/v1`. Here `kk` corresponds to `this.$route.params.filterId` and `v1` to `this.$route.params.version`.

Comment: Could you please give some examples of the results you want? Also include the route params that would produce those results

Comment: @Phil I've made the edits.

Comment: Why would there be two `v1` entries? Only one _filter_ matches `filterId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to *filter* the `myFilters` object but instead (flat) *map* the values within to the matching versions

```js
const result = [{"myFilters":[{"isMatch":false,"filters":[{"id":"aaaaaa","version":"v1"},{"id":"kk","version":"v1"}]}],"randomAttr1":null,"randomAttr2":[]}]

this.$route = {params:{filterId:"kk",version:"v1"}}

// this avoids mutating `results`
const modifiedResult = result.map(f => ({
  ...f,
  relevant_versions: f.myFilters.flatMap(({ filters }) =>
    filters.filter(({ id, version }) =>
      id == this.$route.params.filterId && version == this.$route.params.version
    ).map(({ version }) => version)
  )
}))

console.info(modifiedResult)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

If you do want to mutate `result`, then replace the top-level `map` with a `forEach` or use a `for..of` loop like in your question

```js
result.forEach(f => {
  f.relevant_versions = f.myFilters.flatMap(...)
})

// or

for (let f of result) {
  f.relevant_versions = f.myFilters.flatMap(...)
}
```